# How to make the result displayed as multiply line NOT one line for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.movie.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5785b86a69a81b093ef402d6"), "name1" : "Test1", "name2" : "Test2", "name3" : "Test3", "name4" : "Test4", "name5" : "Test5", "name6" : "Test6", "name7" : "Test7", "name8" : "Test8", "name9" : "Test9", "name10" : "Test10", "name11" : "Test11", "name12" : "Test12", "name13" : "Test13"  }
MongoDB Enterprise >
```

This is my cmd line result.
However, I don't know how to config so that the result displayed as below style:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5785b86a69a81b093ef402d6"),
    "name1" : "Test1",
    "name2" : "Test2",
    "name3" : "Test3",
    "name4" : "Test4",
    "name5" : "Test5",
    "name6" : "Test6",
    "name7" : "Test7",
    "name8" : "Test8",
    "name9" : "Test9",
    "name10" : "Test10",
    "name11" : "Test11",
    "name12" : "Test12",
    "name13" : "Test13"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NePj7.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question has already been answered... what you're looking for is the "pretty print" cursor option in the `mongo` shell.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, Stennie.
The pretty print way is fixed my question.